# Creating an aggregated data from random dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to do below.

I have a `sales` table with past year sales figures for several product items (ABC1, ABC2, ..., ABC7).

```
Invoice Number  Date        Product ID  Sales
........       .........       ....      ..
IN000945       1/01/2019       ABC1      2
IN000946       2/01/2019       ABC2      4
IN000947       2/01/2019       ABC1      6
IN000948       4/01/2019       ABC1      1
IN000949       4/01/2019       ABC1      9
IN000950       4/01/2019       ABC3      10
IN000951       4/01/2019       ABC6      1
IN000952       8/01/2019       ABC2      12
IN000953       9/01/2019       ABC2      3
........       .........       ....      ..
IN567953       31/12/2019      ABC7      12
........       .........       ....      ..
```

**Requirement**
I want to create a table with the following data. It will be used to train a model.

1. I only want records from ABC1, ABC2 and ABC3 products.
2. Within the past year date range, I want to select 160 random dates (for e.g) and calculate the following.
3. From a random date, calculate past week data, past 4-week data, and future 4-week data.
4. **Data is always available for generating summary data for any edge date. for example, 31/12/2019. In the analysis we are only interested in calculating it for past year data.**

   **I don't want to get random dates from the dates in the table. Instead, I want to generate random dates from all possible 365 dates of the past year, even if there are no specific records for that date. And for a given date, I want aggregated data for all 3 products. So for a given date, there will 3 records, as shown in the final output table.**

The final table will look something similar to this.

```
Date       Product  Past week   Past 4 week Future 4 week
4/03/2019   ABC1    12           34              34
4/03/2019   ABC2    11           52              24
4/03/2019   ABC3    6            23              45
8/06/2019   ABC1    15           34              32
8/06/2019   ABC2    13           45              65
8/06/2019   ABC3    12           56              34
14/09/2019  ABC1    12           65              32
14/09/2019  ABC2    14           12              26
14/09/2019  ABC3    12           76              31
..........  ....    ..           ..              ..
12/10/2019  ABC3    15           34              25
```

I can't figure out how to approach this problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does your source table have a primary key?

Comment: What happens where random row happens to be Jan 1st or Dec 31st?

Comment: @PM77-1 Actually data is available for longer time (than specified in the question), and it is always guaranteed that you have necessary data available for calculation. Added a note in the question.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes unique ID is also available for each of the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have presented not enough data to play around with.

The sales are calculated by summning all data of a product for the tree time period

The random 180 dates are selected by ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 180 in the inner SELECT query

The ORDER BY t1.date is important, because if you donÄ't put the t1 there is take the converted text as basis, and string order is dieffrent from dazes

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales
>     (`Invoice Number` varchar(8), `Date` varchar(10), `Product ID` varchar(4), `Sales` varchar(2))
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sales
>     (`Invoice Number`, `Date`, `Product ID`, `Sales`)
> VALUES
>     ('IN000945', '15/08/2019', 'ABC1', '2'),
>     ('IN000946', '16/08/2019', 'ABC2', '4'),
>     ('IN000947', '17/08/2019', 'ABC1', '6'),
>     ('IN000948', '18/08/2019', 'ABC1', '1'),
>     ('IN000949', '19/08/2019', 'ABC1', '9'),
>     ('IN000950', '20/08/2019', 'ABC3', '10'),
>     ('IN000951', '21/08/2019', 'ABC6', '1'),
>     ('IN000952', '22/08/2019', 'ABC2', '12'),
>     ('IN000953', '23/08/2019', 'ABC2', '3'),
>     ('IN000945', '1/09/2019', 'ABC1', '2'),
>     ('IN000946', '2/09/2019', 'ABC2', '4'),
>     ('IN000947', '2/09/2019', 'ABC1', '6'),
>     ('IN000948', '4/09/2019', 'ABC1', '1'),
>     ('IN000949', '4/09/2019', 'ABC1', '9'),
>     ('IN000950', '4/09/2019', 'ABC3', '10'),
>     ('IN000951', '4/09/2019', 'ABC6', '1'),
>     ('IN000952', '8/09/2019', 'ABC2', '12'),
>     ('IN000953', '9/09/2019', 'ABC2', '3')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, '%d/%m/%Y') `Date`,
>     `Product ID`,
>     saleslast1week,
>     saleslast28,
>     salesfuture28
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         @date:=STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d/%m/%Y') `Date`,
>             @Product:=`Product ID` `Product ID`,
>             (SELECT 
>                     SUM(`Sales`)
>                 FROM
>                     sales
>                 WHERE
>                     `Product ID` = @Product
>                         AND STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d/%m/%Y') >= @date - INTERVAL 7 DAY
>                         AND STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d/%m/%Y') <= @date
>                 GROUP BY `Product ID`) saleslast1week,
>             (SELECT 
>                     SUM(`Sales`)
>                 FROM
>                     sales
>                 WHERE
>                     `Product ID` = @Product
>                         AND STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d/%m/%Y') >= @date - INTERVAL 28 DAY
>                         AND STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d/%m/%Y') <= @date
>                 GROUP BY `Product ID`) saleslast28,
>             (SELECT 
>                     SUM(`Sales`)
>                 FROM
>                     sales
>                 WHERE
>                     `Product ID` = @Product
>                         AND STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d/%m/%Y') <= @date + INTERVAL 28 DAY
>                         AND STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d/%m/%Y') >= @date
>                 GROUP BY `Product ID`) salesfuture28
>     FROM
>         sales
>     WHERE
>         `Product ID` IN ('ABC1' , 'ABC2', 'ABC3')
>             AND STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d/%m/%Y') >= NOW() - INTERVAL 14 MONTH
>     ORDER BY RAND()
>     LIMIT 180) t1
> ORDER BY t1.`Date`
> ```
>
> ```
> Date       | Product ID | saleslast1week | saleslast28 | salesfuture28
> :--------- | :--------- | -------------: | ----------: | ------------:
> 15/08/2019 | ABC1       |              2 |           2 |            36
> 16/08/2019 | ABC2       |              4 |           4 |            38
> 17/08/2019 | ABC1       |              8 |           8 |            34
> 18/08/2019 | ABC1       |              9 |           9 |            28
> 19/08/2019 | ABC1       |             18 |          18 |            27
> 20/08/2019 | ABC3       |             10 |          10 |            20
> 22/08/2019 | ABC2       |             16 |          16 |            34
> 23/08/2019 | ABC2       |             19 |          19 |            22
> 01/09/2019 | ABC1       |              2 |          20 |            18
> 02/09/2019 | ABC1       |              8 |          26 |            16
> 02/09/2019 | ABC2       |              4 |          23 |            19
> 04/09/2019 | ABC3       |             10 |          20 |            10
> 04/09/2019 | ABC1       |             18 |          36 |            10
> 04/09/2019 | ABC1       |             18 |          36 |            10
> 08/09/2019 | ABC2       |             16 |          35 |            15
> 09/09/2019 | ABC2       |             19 |          38 |             3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6a9858c5c84c6b996cd1b6101355ecbf)*

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The future values are not predicted but are calculated from table data. For example, if the randomly selected date is 12/03/2019. The future column value will be calculated by summing all the values in the table for the productID up to next 4 weeks from that date.

Comment: I added the "future" days , but they follow the same pattern.

Comment: Thank you. Now, this is almost what I need, but the random date generation should be different. I don't want to get random dates from the dates in the table. Instead, I want to generate random dates from all possible 365 dates of the past year, even if there are no specific records for that date.  And for a given date, I want aggregated data for all 3 products. So for a given date, there will 3 records, as shown in the final output table.

Comment: Loomk it does this. run the query on your data, it makes exactly that. What it doesn't do lets say on January thge 4 you didd' seel any abc3 then it doesn't show this. that is eays remedied. But it select  180 rtandom  days of all. as you can see the example i build has not that many days, so you must run the query on your system.